# AngularJS accordion with ng-click giving errors

Tags: angularjs, accordion, angularjs-ng-click

I am getting the following error

> Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

when i try to use the angularJS accordian widget. The full error is [here](http://pastebin.com/v6UrK83B). The only difference is that my accordian-group has a method call on the ng-click. If i remove the ng-click, it seems to work ok. Any feedback on why this would be happening?

```
  <accordion close-others="false">

    <accordion-group heading="{{data.title}}" ng-repeat="datum in data" ng-click="getdata(data.path)">
      {{data.content}}
    </accordion-group>

  </accordion>
```

Comment: What does the `getdata()` look like? Please include its code.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose the code under your getData() function into $timeout may be that should fix the problem.

Comment: It *might* remove the symptom, but probably not fix the underlying problem.